# Check if a hash set contains an elements with a specific hash value

Tags: java, hash, hashset

Assume that we have a hash set of the objects of class `Node` which the class `Node` is defined as follows :

```
class Node{
  int id;
  public int hash(){
     return id;
  }
}
```

We want to check if the hash set contains an element with id `n` , how can we do that without having the object ?

Comment: Have you tried anything? Does it work?

Comment: Actually the reason I'm asking is that I didn't find anything.

Answer (score 1):

You can't, the use of hash code is an internal implementation of the HashSet class, but the Set interface don't talk about hash codes.

I suggest you to use an alternative structure like a Map where you store the objects by id and then you can check if a certain id is present or not.

Answer (score 1):

```
boolean contains = mySet.contains(new Node(n));
```

Comment: I depends what is done in constructor (see e.g. http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/149563/should-we-avoid-object-creation-in-java)